# Creating square grid polygons from shapefile using ArcGIS Desktop and machine learning to predict wildfires

Tags: arcgis-desktop, machine-learning

I'm currently working on a data science project where I would like to predict the probability of a wildfire in Washington state for a given location using machine learning.

I have latitude/longitude observations for historical wildfires. However, I need the negative class as well.

I am considering taking a Washington state shape file and breaking it down into small grid polygons to serve as my unit of observation. If a wildfire falls into that grid, then that grid is labelled as the positive class. I plan on layering other features such as topography, ecosystem, biomass counts, etc.

I'm struggling on how to create these small grids. I've been playing with ArcGIS Desktop for a few days now.

Could anyone point me in the right direction or provide a sanity check on whether this is a good approach?

Comment: It sounds like you want a fishnet http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-fishnet.htm, is that correct?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  I have reduced the scope of your question to omit Python for now because for questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Are you using the ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap application of ArcGIS Desktop?